# Trying to create a shell script with 2 menus to do additions and subtractions

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, menu

This is what I have so far. I really can't figure out how to call Menu2 from another function. I always get an error whenever I try to run it. Also for some reason from the first menu, I need to type "X" twice before it actually quits. One more thing, after the calculation has been done it returns to Menu 2 for some reason when I need it to return to Menu.

*EDIT*  If i replace the "break" in cpick() with "Menu2" it never executes Menu2. It loops back to Menu. Sorry, the error I was getting was because I was unsure of how to call a function in a function. I was trying "Menu2()" instead of Menu.

*EDIT 2* Problem#1: The "*****" were just to hide my name :) 
Problem#2: Thank you that worked! 
Problem#3: I don't really understand what you're suggesting... :S 
Problem#4: The way I currently have it seems to work like I want it to so I'm going to change it, its just aesthetics :P

Im still unable to figure out how to get back to Menu after the calculation has been done. Im unable to call the Menu function in my apick(). What I want it to do is return to Menu once the calculation has been completed rather then returning to Menu2.

```
#!/bin/sh
LOGO=" Shell Scripting - Created by *****"

cmenu="C)  Calculation";
xmenu="X)  Exit";
amenu="+)  Add";
smenu="-)  Substract";

badchoice () { MSG="Invalid Selection ... Please Try Again" ;} 

cpick () { clear
           read -p "Please enter an integer number or X to exit: " num1 
           clear
           break
           echo; }
apick () { clear
           read -p "Please enter an integer number or X to exit: " num2
           sum=$(($num1+$num2))
           echo The sum of $num1 plus $num2 equals $sum
           sleep 3;}
spick () { clear
           read -p "Please enter an integer number or X to exit: " num2
           diff=$(($num1-$num2))
           echo The difference of $num1 minus $num2 equals $diff
           sleep 3;}
xpick () { break;} 


Menu() {
 clear
 echo `date`
 echo
 echo "\t" $LOGO
 echo
 echo "Please Select:"
 echo
 echo "\t" $cmenu
 echo "\t" $xmenu
 echo $MSG
 echo Please choose a letter above then hit Enter;
  }

Menu2() {
clear
echo `date`
echo 
echo "Please Select:"
echo
echo "\t" $amenu
echo "\t" $smenu
echo "\t" $xmenu
echo $MSG
echo Please choose an option above then hit Enter; 
}



 while  true
 do

  Menu
   read answer

   MSG=

   case $answer in
       c|C) cpick;;
       x|X) break;;
       *) badchoice;;

   esac
done 


 while true
 do

 Menu2
   read answer

   MSG=

   case $answer in
       +) apick;;
       -) spick;;
       x|X) xpick;;
       *) badchoice;;

   esac
done
```

Comment: You need to type x twice, because first exits from the first while loop, second exits from the second while loop. The break in the function will not exits the while. Could you specify what error message you get?

Answer (score 0):

Problem#1: LOGO contains a `*` character. You should add double quote marks around. Example:

```
X="*"
echo $X
echo "$X"
```

Output:

```
file1 file2 ...
*
```

Problem#2: In the first `case` use `exit` if `x` entered.

Problem#3: `break` defined in shell function will not break the case. Enter `break` explicitly in `case`.

Problem#4. `echo "\t"` prints `\t` in linux. Enter `echo -e "\t"` to print a tab.

Then it will work...